# RPC Authentication

Tags: c++, authentication, ipc, rpc, interprocess

I'm working on communicating data on local machine using Remote Procedure Calls ( RPC ). My requirement is use RPC to communicate data between two processed, but server should authenticate client by some means.

I came across RpcBindingSetAuthInfo which set authentication and authorization information. The fourth parameter is authentication service which can be anything from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373556(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

WINNT authentication is not applicable in my case since client does not run under any particular user. Looking at the documentation, I don't understand which authentication service would be applicable in my case. I need some way to authenticate the client based on some token etc. It would be great if someone could shed some light/ give some pointers of RPC authentication.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes token generation is what we use in our product as well . For e.g when the client requests to connect to the server , after authentication the server generates a unique id which it sends to the client . Now the client creates an instance of the server interface and which returns a pointer on which all the further communication can take place . When the client disconnects , the server unregisters or removes the unique id from its list of client's connected

Comment: Do you meant I don't need to use RPCSecurityCallback for authentication. Can you put some code to explain the approach in detailed.